# Finding smallest subset of vertices - backtracking?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, backtracking

let E - set of all edges in graph G
The problem is to find the smallest subset S of vertices from G, which satisfies condition:
sum of all outgoing edges from each vertex in S = E

In other words:
Edges are streets and we can place street lamps on the vertices. If we place a street lamp on a vertex - all outgoing streets from this vertex are lightened. How to find the cheapes way to make all streets lightened?

Is there something better than backtracking?

Comment: Yes, there are better ways to solve [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

Comment: thanks, I couldn't name my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an np-complete problem. But as always there are many near optimal solutions. Try [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrVPW0PacC8)